# laravel exists validation for more columns with OR

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-4

I want to check `active_status` of a user is `A` **OR** `S` in the validation, this is what i did and it check only `active_status` is sets to `A`, and now i want to extends it to check the condition `A` **OR** `S`

```
$checkUserActiveInMyPageRules = Array(
    'user' => 'required|exists:user,id,active_status,A'
);
```

is there any inbuilt option in laravel to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check for a set of values using built-in **exists** validation, so you'll need to extend the **Validator** with your custom validation.

```
Validator::extend('exists_with_attribute', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
  $table = $parameters[0];
  $column = $parameters[1];
  $checkColumn = $parameters[2];
  $checkValues = array_slice($parameters, 3);

  return DB::table($table)->where($column, $value)->whereIn($checkColumn, $checkValues)->count() > 0;
});
```

and use it in your validation rules

```
$checkUserActiveInMyPageRules = Array(
  'user' => 'required|exists_with_attribute,id,active_status,A,S'
);
```

See the docs for more details about extending validator functionality: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#custom-validation-rules